# A simple asp.net feature

Tags: asp.net

When I would be able to write :

```
<asp:TextBox id="Input" runat="server"/> <asp:Button onclick="<% Input.Text='my input' %>" />
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have a clue what your question is here. Could you please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: The whole point of asp.net is not to do that. OnClick is an event that encapsulates your logic. Why would you slap that logic in one line of code in your page markup?

Comment: haha, interesting to see people reacting differently to this question. but no one realized the need for this cool feature. The way ternary operator in C, and lambda expressions in LINQ provide a shorthand for simple statements, this feature could very well provide that same convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately with standard WebForms this simply isn't possible. The `On<EventName>` property expects a string which must correspond to the name of a method whose signature matches the event's handler delegate.

Essentially what you are describing is the ability to, inline, assign a lambda to be invoked when the event is raised. To add this functionality you would need to build your own ViewEngine to replace the existing WebForms one. This is hardly a trivial task, but it is possible, and it would be a very cool feature to have.

Comment: At least you got it right. This will provide a quick and dirty way to write those simple single statements which now needs an event handler to be declared and so on. 
With some thoughtfullness, this can combine client side data and server side event handlers too.